# WSO2 WSF/Ruby - anyone using it?

Tags: ruby, web-services

Have been using [Savon](https://github.com/rubiii/savon) for my webservice stuff so far, but need to talk to a more "secure" service now, needing WS Addressing and WS Security Extensions.

Have started to extend this [fork](https://github.com/carnesmedia/savon) of Savon to handle it, but then found [WSO2 WSF/Ruby](http://wso2.org/project/wsf/ruby/1.1.0/docs/manual.html) - so wondering if anyone has any experience of it, pros/cons etc.  That is, is it worth my switching to it?  I cant see much out there about it, besides on their own site - their forums seem awfully quiet, which does not bode well.

Currently dev on OSX/Snow Leopard, deploying on CentOS.

Thanks in advance,
Chris

Comment: so did you decide to use WSO2? i'm currently facing the same problem but it's related to MTOM support and the lack of it in every existing soap library for ruby

Comment: Nope - procrastinated long enough on it that the developers of the endpoint decided to make it a little more open/Savon friendly - win :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It does not seem so (from the lack of replies...)